# Count viable combinations of events given schedule of simultaneously meeting classes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Scenario:

- A set of students ('001', '002'...) each have a set of classes they need to attend at school.
- The schedule is a list of which classes are happening for each period of the school day, grouped into sets of classes that are happening at the same time
- The task is to analyse how 'good' a given schedule is, where good means that every student will be able to attend all of the classes they need, in as many different permutations as possible

Problem description:

Given a hash:

```
 hash = {
    '001' => ['MX1','EF1','HG1','PN1','SP1','AU1'],
    '002' => ['MP1','EF1','HG2','PN4','SC1','AU3'],
    '003' => ['MG1','EF2','HP1','PP1','SC1','AU1']
    }
```

and a two dimensional array:

```
schedule = [
['MX1','EF2','XE1','SP1','AU4'],
['MX1','EF1','HP1','PP1','AU1'],
['MP1','MG1','SP1','HG2','PN1','AU1','MX1','EG1','HG1'],
['MG1','EF2','PN4','SC1','AU1','SP1'],
['PP1','PN1','PN4','EF1','EF2'],
['SC1','PP1','HP1','AU1']
]
```

I want to discover in how many different ways the elements from the `hash` value can be matched with the arrays from `schedule`, resulting in a result hash:

```
{
'001' => 1,  # just using example values, this is a count
'002' => 0,  # of the combinations of the array from hash
'003' => 2   # that can be matched to each array in schedule
} 

         # without replacement
```

A 'match' means that, given a value array from hash:
    `['MX1','EF1','HG1','PN1','SP1','AU1']`
each element can be found in a different array from `schedule`.

One match for `hash['001']` is:

```
{
'MX1' => schedule[0], # given here in hash form only
'EF1' => schedule[1], # for illustrative purposes,
'HG1' => schedule[2], # I don't need to represent
'PN1' => schedule[4], # each match
'SP1' => schedule[3],
'AU1' => schedule[5]
}
```

If there are students with 0 possible matches we know that we have to move some classes, and the more matches possible for every student, the better the schedule.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a site to help users with problems they have attempted, but failed, to solve. It appears you have not made an attempt, or if you have, you have not shown what you tried. Please post your work and ask for help in a specific area.

Comment: As per my understanding, you wants to get the count of minimum occurrence of values from `hash` (variable name) in `schedule` array. Let's say, in `hash['001']`, `MX1` is occurred thrice but other values are `HG1` is occurred once. So the final output of of key `'001'` will be `1`. Am I right?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not so sure if it's always going to be the min.

Comment: @HoMan I mean the output will be the count of least occurred element.

Comment: Interesting problem. I suggest you simplify by asking the number of ways a single student can take all their classes. Once you have that it's trivial to repeat that for each student. Also, I think it would be clearer if,j at the outset, you say the elements of the arrays are subjects (rather than giving that interpretation later). Even better would be to have elements such as `:history_10`, `math_11` and so on.

Comment: Is it something like, `schedule.flatten!` and then `hash.each_pair { |k, v| hash[k] = v.map { |e| schedule.count(e) }.min }`. Output: `{"001"=>1, "002"=>0, "003"=>2}`

Comment: Taking just the count won't work I think. Imagine if the subjects all fit into `[3,5]` for all the classes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a student must take the following classes:

```
classes = ['MX1','EF1','HG1','PN1','SP1','AU1']
```

First, for efficiency, convert `schedule` to an array of sets.

```
require 'set'

sch_sets = schedule.map { |a| a.to_set }
  #=> [#<Set: {"MX1", "EF2", "XE1", "SP1", "AU4"}>,
  #    #<Set: {"MX1", "EF1", "HP1", "PP1", "AU1"}>,
  #    #<Set: {"MP1", "MG1", "SP1", "HG2", "PN1", "AU1", "MX1", "EG1", "HG1"}>,
  #    #<Set: {"MG1", "EF2", "PN4", "SC1", "AU1", "SP1"}>,
  #    #<Set: {"PP1", "PN1", "PN4", "EF1", "EF2"}>,
  #    #<Set: {"SC1", "PP1", "HP1", "AU1"}>]
```

Then repeat the following for each student.

```
classes.permutation(classes.size).
        count { |p| sch_sets.zip(p).all? { |s,cl|  s.include?(cl) } }
  #=> 1
```

For those curious about the permutation that works in this case, we need only change `count` to `select` (or, since here there is only one, `find`).

```
classes.permutation(classes.size).
        select { |p| sch_sets.zip(p).all? { |s,cl| s.include?(cl) } }
  #=> [["MX1", "EF1", "HG1", "SP1", "PN1", "AU1"]]
```

See docs for the following instance methods.

- `permutation` and `size` for the class [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html)
- `include?` for the class [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)
- `count`, `zip`, `all?` and `select` for the included module [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html)

The instance method `to_set` is added to `Enumerable` when `Set` is required (see the second paragraph of the `Set` doc).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I put the implementation info up top and I'm going to convert to the clear class symbols that you suggested, and make the change to sets as well.

This is so interesting, I felt sure that what I was trying to do was possible like this- my attempt ran two hundred lines and I couldn't figure out how to do it without replacement (a student with the classes in you exam would count as valid if 'MX1' appeared in every set)

Off to learn about the zip method but I'll return to make those updates once I've wrapped my head about this logic, thank you again